# Retrieve memory usage for another process in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management

I've seen methods here for retrieving CPU and memory usage for the CURRENT process, i.e. 'my application', but I need to write a service that monitors the performance of a separate application.

In C++ I used PSAPI for this, but I'm new to C# and would like to use the managed framework if possible.  Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        long memory;
        Process[] notepads;
        notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad.exe");
        memory = notepads[0].PrivateMemorySize64;
        Console.WriteLine("Memory used: {0}.", memory);
more info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s80a75e5(v=vs.90).aspx
```

Comment: thanks, although I had to use Path.GetFIleNameWithoutExtension(exe-name) to get this to work...

Comment: What about the current process in .NET core in a cross-platform way? (to work with Windows and Linux)

Comment: Had to use `"Notepad"` without extension.